# realloc - converting int to char

Tags: c, string, ncurses, realloc

I'm converting an array of integers into a char by iterating through the whole array, and then I'm adding the resulting string to ncurses's method `new_item`. For some reason I'm doing something wrong the way I `reallocate` memory, thus I get the the first column as:

```
-4 Choice 1                 0 Choice 1
 4 Choice 2                 1 Choice 1
 4 Choice 3  - Instead of - 2 Choice 1
 4 Choice 4                 3 Choice 1
 4 Exit                     4 Choice 1
```

-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <menu.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define CTRLD     4

char *choices[] = {
                        "Choice 1",
                        "Choice 2",
                        "Choice 3",
                        "Choice 4",
                        "Exit",
                  };
int table[5]={0,1,2,3,4}; 
int main()
{    ITEM **my_items;
    int c;              
    MENU *my_menu;
    int n_choices, i;
    ITEM *cur_item;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    n_choices = ARRAY_SIZE(choices);
    my_items = (ITEM **)calloc(n_choices + 1, sizeof(ITEM *));

    char *convert = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i){
        convert = (char *) malloc ( sizeof(char) * 4);
        sprintf(convert, "%i", table[i]); 
        my_items[i] = new_item(convert, choices[i]);
    }
    my_items[n_choices] = (ITEM *)NULL;

    my_menu = new_menu((ITEM **)my_items);
    mvprintw(LINES - 2, 0, "F1 to Exit");
    post_menu(my_menu);
    refresh();

    while((c = getch()) != KEY_F(1))
    {   switch(c)
        {   case KEY_DOWN:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_DOWN_ITEM);
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                menu_driver(my_menu, REQ_UP_ITEM);
                break;
        }
    }

    char *n = NULL, *d = NULL;

    unpost_menu(my_menu);
    free_menu(my_menu);
    for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i){
       n = (char *) item_name (my_items[i]);
       free (n);
       d = (char *) item_description (my_items[i]);
       free (d);
       free_item(my_items[i]);
    }

    free(my_items);
    endwin();
}
```

**Update: This has been fixed. See code above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempt to [`realloc`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) the same memory block with the same size again and again, for which `realloc` just returns the same memory block. So you are overwriting the earlier values of `convert`, and storing the same char array in all items.

You should use `malloc` instead:

```
// right here
char *convert = NULL;
for(i = 0; i < n_choices; ++i){
    convert = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * 4);
    sprintf(convert, "%i", table[i]); 
    my_items[i] = new_item(convert, choices[i]);
}
```

Comment: I actually did, (see code above) but valgrind throws 
16 bytes in 4 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 21
at 0x4023D6E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)

Comment: @Mike: you also have to clean up all the memory you allocate.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Am I missing something that I need to clean up?  I'm freeing convert

Comment: @Mike: you only free up the last of the values allocated to `convert`; you need to clean up each the values - the ones assigned via the `new_item()` function to `my_items[i]`.  Exactly how you do that I'm not sure; I'm not familiar with this specific `new_item()`.  But since you iterate around the loop a number of times, allocating each time, but only free once, you are bound to be leaking memory (or, possibly, double-freeing - but Valgrind is saying you're leaking, not double-freeing).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thanks, as you mentioned, I wasn't freeing each of the values.